# Django json serialization problem

Tags: django, json, serialization

I am having difficulty serializing a django object.  The problem is that there are foreign keys.  I want the serialization to have data from the referenced object, not just the index.

For example, I would like the sponsor data field to say "sponsor.last_name, sponsor.first_name" rather than "13".

How can I fix my serialization?

json data:
{"totalCount":"2","activities":[{"pk": 1, "model": "app.activity", "fields": {"activity_date": "2010-12-20", "description": "my activity", "sponsor": 13, "location": 1, ....

model code:

```
class Activity(models.Model): 
  activity_date = models.DateField()
  description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  sponsor = models.ForeignKey(Sponsor)
  location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Sponsor(models.Model):
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  first_name= models.CharField(max_length=20)
  specialty = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Location(models.Model):
  location_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  location_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def activityJSON(request):
    activities = Activity.objects.all()
    total = activities.count()
    activities_json = serializers.serialize("json", activities)
    data = "{\"totalCount\":\"%s\",\"activities\":%s}" % (total, activities_json)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
```

Answer (score 2):

Add relations to the serializer like this:

```
activities_json = serializers.serialize("json", activities, relations=('sponsor',))
```

Then all you need is:

```
return HttpResponse(activities_json, mimetype="application/json")
```

Then make sure you also have the django library wadofstuff installed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) seem to explain exactly how to do this. Read the part about serialization of natural keys.

Answer (score 1):

This small lib is very handy with django : http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers

It allows more customisation than the standard encoder.

Answer (score 0):

**any2any** also contains serializers allowing to customize completely the output format :

- [check the docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/any2any/en/latest/doc_pages/djangocast.html)
- [repo on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/sebpiq/any2any)
- [or on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/any2any/0.1)